# GIS Chat and the Hot Network Questions

Tags: discussion, chat

Many of you know of, and occasionally use, the [GIS SE Chat Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/939/gis).  In January of this year I modified the chat room to also include a feed that posted a link to GIS SE Questions whenever they feature on the Stack Exchange Network's "Hot Network Questions".

Hot Network Questions (HNQs) tend to bring additional traffic from outside our regular GIS users, which can mean more votes, comments, and hopefully answers to our "hot" questions.  I liked the idea of having a feed of the GIS HNQs as I wasn't fully aware which of our questions ended up there, and it was nice to be able to identify them easily.

Since this feed has now been in the GIS chat room for about 3 months, I am interested to hear what the users think of having the feed in that chat room.  Is it good or bad?  Do you use the links from the feed to see our HNQs?  Does it discourage you from using the chat room?  Do you think you miss any interesting or important chat messages because the feed clogs the chat?  Is there less chat in the chat room as a result?

If you like it, what do you like about it?  If you don't, what about it don't you like?  What changes would you like to see made to it?

I would love to hear your thoughts, good or bad, on having the HNQ in GIS Chat Room, and any suggestions you might have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I liked the idea of having a feed of the GIS HNQs as I wasn't fully aware which of our questions ended up there, and it was nice to be able to identify them easily.

I liked it too (thanks). This is a pro.

> Do you think you miss any interesting or important chat messages because the feed clogs the chat?

Yes. This is a con. Normally, a HNQ won't be a target of a debate or dicussion to justify it being there in the main chat room.

> What changes would you like to see made to it?

Create a specific room to house the HNQ feed. Maybe name it 'GIS HNQs'.

**Edit:**

**However**, one caveat is that the feed alone won't prevent the room from being frozen or deleted ([Do messages from feeds prevent freezing/deleting a chat room?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238911/do-messages-from-feeds-prevent-freezing-deleting-a-chat-room)), if no one else post messages there regularly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I can definitely make a GIS HNQ chat room.  There is a small issue that someone needs to chat in there at least once a week to keep it alive (otherwise it is frozen and hidden).  But that can be overcome

Comment: Hum, I thought the feed feeding it with question links would count as messages; thus preventing freezing. @Midavalo

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the case - the chat rooms don't see the feed as user content so still freezes the room.  It'll just take someone (with permissions applied) to comment every week to keep it alive

Comment: I see. If you decide creating the new room, I can help commenting there. @Midavalo

Comment: I have created a new GIS Hot Network Questions chat room.  I will post separately on Meta once I'm sure it's working properly

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't aware of the GIS chat room until just now. Visiting it, I see that the 11 most recent messages are all automated HNQ posts.

[image]

That's a bad ratio, and would certainly completely discourage me from posting there.

Comment: But is this ratio bad just because nobody uses chat, or is the chat use lower because of the HNQ?  I suspect it's the former, but at least having it separate would make it easier to find other chat messages

Comment: Well by definition the first is true. The second contributes to some degree, presumably, but hard to say.